# How to capture 120fps video in iPhone 5s using AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, iphone-5

I'm developing an app that needs to capture highspeed video. I use AVFoundation. But how to set it to capture 120fps (like the iOS camera app, slow mo). Besides, can I limit my app to iPhone 5s only?